# не удается импортировать телебот в питон

Tags: python, telebot, python-import

я запускаю программу но пишет что может вы имели введу telebot а не  Telebot  а когда исправляю то представляете нету такого модуля вся проблема в строке 3

```
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot('6305243252:AAEhQzdbKa0aMH1m4J5SWOH0aPluoEiOv7k')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])

def start(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '<b>Привет</b>', parse_mode='html')


bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: Посоветую вам удалять токен бота при показе кода бота третим лицам, иначе кто-то может его использовать в не самых лучших целей, а сейчас лучше перегенерировать токен бота

Comment: дубликаты где-то [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=no+module+named+telebot)

Comment: Вы библиотеку через `pip install pyTelegramBotAPI` установили?

Answer (score 0):

Вы вероятно поставили не ту библиотеку, попробуйте:

```
pip install python-telegram-bot
```

Comment: Ну, это только одна из десятка возможных причин.

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/881421)

Comment: @ЧёткаяЧетырка а кстати автор уже "достиг необходимого уровня..." :)